# How to call other extensions in a extension on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Here is my demand, I want to startup a debug session with some dynamic arguments.
So I need to develop a extension that collect the arguments at first and register a debugger wrapper to vscode, after that I have to find a way to call the target extension's debugger with my arguments.

`vscode.extensions.getExtension` can get extension's informations and be able to active it only.

I found a command named "debug.startFromConfig" in vscode's sources, so I can use `vscode.commands.executeCommand` to execute it with my own configuration.
But unfortunately I can't use vscode's api on a debug adapter, since it's not a extension host which just a single node programe.

The follow is what I expected, I have a debugger wrapper named `asd`
[image: debugger description]

And I'm going to override some configurations of python debugger by my own debugger.(These codes following can't work, I explained that on above)
[image: code]

After that I can run my custom debugger to call the python debugger
[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you not using the official startDebugging extension API? Please see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/31221e62995c7040400051c2353c3c7c8b303c16/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L8874.

Alternatively you could register a DebugConfigurationProvider for the debug types you are interested in and intercept the "resolveDebugConfiguration" method in order to adapt the launch configuration dynamically. Please see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/31221e62995c7040400051c2353c3c7c8b303c16/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L8544.

Yes, vscode.d.ts is your friend...

Comment: Excellent, I read the debugger docs again and solved it just now. Yes, I use the `DebugConfigurationProvider` too, I just want to answer it by myself and saw your answer, thanks a lot :)